# MultiSelect combobox in modern ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Something strange has happened and easy-to-use property [multiSelect](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-multiSelect) has gone deprected for some reason. Documentation advises to

> Use {@link Ext.form.field.Tag} or {@link Ext.view.MultiSelector}

but does not provide any example. So if I have an ordinary combobox, how can I make it multiselectable?

Comment: Please change you question to "Multiselect combobox in classic Extjs", you have accpeted the answer so it means you are using classic toolkit

Comment: and tag field is not available in modern modern toolkit, is it?

Comment: @Jacobian The words "Modern" and "Classic" refer to very specific versions of ExtJS.  As written, the title of this question is awfully confusing.  Please correct the title as Waqar has already requested and I will remove my down-vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of an ordinary `combobox` with `multiSelect`, you should use `tagfield`. Configuration is basically the same.

```
{
    xtype: 'tagfield',
    fieldLabel: 'My first tagfield',
    store: {
        ...
    },
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    queryMode: 'local',
}
```

You can checkout an example [here](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/kitchensink/#form-tag)

Comment: I don't know why he accepted the answer but modern toolkit doesn't have tagfield

Comment: By modern I meant ExtJS 6 and not its material design version

Comment: How would do possibly do that in ExtReact.?